# SAS Concatenation requires character operands

Tags: sas, concatenation

The code below is attempting to concat two dates and place a forward slash between them. However the error of requiring operands is populated. Thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
MONTH(ORIG_DT)||'/'||YEAR(ORIG_DT) AS ORIG_MONTH_YEAR
```

The database has this field stored as  Date.

If the respective date in the field is date is 6/11/2019, I want the query to return 6/2019.

Comment: Did you try using the `CATX()` function instead?

Comment: You should include the error as well, MONTH() and YEAR() return numbers not characters therefore you receive an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SAS, why not use a format to do this rather than messing around with string functions? E.g. if you don't mind having one leading zero, you could do this:

```
ORIG_DT format = mmyyn8. as ORIG_MONTH_YEAR
```

Comment: Thank you.  Fairly new to SAS and this worked great.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you need to convert each of the numbers to character before concatenating using the PUT function, e.g.

```
put(month(orig_dt), 2.)||'/'||put(year(orig_dt), 4.)
```